# Как связать таблицы естественным соединением и вывести только строки по условию?

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно вывести те продукты, которые покупались 2-мя или более клиентами.

Пробую связать таблицы, это продукты (ном. продукта, наименование, описание) 
и клиенты (ном. кл., имя).  Надо так же учесть таблицы: заказы (дата зак., дата дост., ном сч.) и позиции (ном заказа, цена покуп., ном. продукта).

По заданию надо использовать естественное соединение таблиц. т.е. без указания колонок.
Пробую так:

```
SELECT "НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ", COUNT("НОМ_КЛ") "КОЛИЧЕСТВО"
FROM STUD."КЛИЕНТЫ", STUD."ПРОДУКТЫ", STUD."ЗАКАЗЫ", STUD."ПОЗИЦИИ"  
GROUP BY "НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ"
HAVING COUNT("НОМ_КЛ")>=2;
```

но не получается, выводится много строк.

Вот [структура таблиц и данные](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50e6756e4603ea61893bfe0035fce0e5)

Comment: Уточни: откуда вывести, какая бд, что ты уже сделал, что нужно вывести.

Comment: Что молодой человек, совсем никак?  Добавте в вопрос структуру таблиц и тестовые данные.

Comment: Можете добавить данные на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6d0462da59164a5f5060d9a6a1ce880). Таблицы я там уже создал, дополните или поправте, если что-то не так.

Comment: Нет, не сохранилось - ORA-00972: identifier is too long, потому, что кириллица. Сделайте сначало на латинице, как показал по ссылке выше, там только данные осталось добавитъ: 3-и продукта, три клиента, и по заказам раскидатъ. Потом переделаете на кириллицу, если потребуют, для решения это никакой роли не играет.

Comment: Вот таблицы и данные к вопросу. - [ссылка](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50e6756e4603ea61893bfe0035fce0e5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В non-ANSI синтаксисе (`table1, table2`) нет естественного соединения таблиц, надо всегда указывать колонки для соединения явно. Используете ANSI синтаксис (*natural join*).

Запрос будет выглядеть так:

```sql
select * from (
    select 
        nom_kl, name, nom_zak, data_zak, nom_prod, naimenovanie, kol_vo,
        count (distinct nom_kl) over (partition by nom_prod) kol_kl
    from  klient k
    natural join zakaz z
    natural join position p
    natural join produkt)
where kol_kl >= 2;
```

Рабочий пример с данными на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=295f307cfba293d7ddd2559cabdc0a77).

---

Строка для подсчёта клиентов, которые купили продукт, работает так:
Аналитическая (или оконная) ф-я `count` посчитает в наборе строк для каждого продукта (`partition by`), кол-во клиентов (`nom_kl`) без повторений (`distinct`), которые в этом наборе строк встречаются.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT PROD, COUNT(KLIENT)
GROUP BY PROD
HAVING COUNT(KLIENT)>2
```